# What is <> meaning...? when we use map <> always is found

Tags: typescript

What is `<>`meaning?
if-state and functions uses `{}`

I can't understand following code...
Anyone make it simple so please tell me about that.
Is `<>`  possible to be used as an argument?

```
const AAA = <K,V> => ( keyMapper: (i: KI) => KO, ...inputs: Map<KI, V>[] ): Map<Key, V[]> => {}
```

Comment: Generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: <> is a type identifier in typescript.

Comment: Type parameters for generics. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is a generic, therefore you specify the types it will use in the angle brackets. `Map<number, string>` for example, means a map with numeric keys and string values.
You can read more about generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html